# select nine item from items[] array shuffled and without duplicate

Tags: javascript

Im trying to select a nine number item from an array item[] shuffled and without duplicates.

but my code is selecting more than nine, with duplicates

how do i change it to get only nine, without duplicates and

how is it possible

what is the change i have to make it possible?

```js
window.onload = rnumber();
function rnumber() {
  const
    items = [  
      { label: '1', url: '1.jpg'  },
      { label: '2', url: '2.jpg'  },
      { label: '3', url: '3.jpg'  },
      { label: '4', url: '4.jpg'  },
      { label: '5', url: '5.jpg'  },
      { label: '6', url: '6.jpg'  },
      { label: '7', url: '7.jpg'  },
      { label: '8', url: '8.jpg'  },
      { label: '9', url: '9.jpg'  },
      { label: '10',url: '10.jpg' }
          ];

  
var lastnumber=0;
for (let index = 0; index < 9; index++) 
  {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
      
  if(lastnumber!=randomIndex)
  {
      item = items[randomIndex];
      lastnumber=randomIndex;
   
   console.log(item);
   }
   else
   {
   rnumber();
   }
     
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select items *without* replacement. You might remove the randomly picked item from the `items` array when you pick it:

```js
window.onload = rnumber();

function rnumber() {
  const items = [  
      { label: '1', url: '1.jpg'  },
      { label: '2', url: '2.jpg'  },
      { label: '3', url: '3.jpg'  },
      { label: '4', url: '4.jpg'  },
      { label: '5', url: '5.jpg'  },
      { label: '6', url: '6.jpg'  },
      { label: '7', url: '7.jpg'  },
      { label: '8', url: '8.jpg'  },
      { label: '9', url: '9.jpg'  },
      { label: '10',url: '10.jpg' }
          ];

  const randItems = Array.from(
    { length: 9 },
    () => {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
      const [item] = items.splice(randomIndex, 1);
      return item;
    }
  );
  console.log(randItems);
}
```

Note that this will *mutate* the original `items` array. If you want to preserve it (like with a deck of cards that can be re-used later), `slice` it first to copy it, and mutate the sliced copy;

```
const slicedItems = items.slice();
// ...
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * slicedItems.length);
const [item] = slicedItems.splice(randomIndex, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use underscore's shuffle method:

```
newitems = _.shuffle(items);
newitems = newitems.splice(0, 9);
```

see https://underscorejs.org/#shuffle

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array of indexes and shuffle is, then use those indexes to pick the elements from you array.

```js
 const items = [  
      { label: '1', url: '1.jpg'  },
      { label: '2', url: '2.jpg'  },
      { label: '3', url: '3.jpg'  },
      { label: '4', url: '4.jpg'  },
      { label: '5', url: '5.jpg'  },
      { label: '6', url: '6.jpg'  },
      { label: '7', url: '7.jpg'  },
      { label: '8', url: '8.jpg'  },
      { label: '9', url: '9.jpg'  },
      { label: '10',url: '10.jpg' }
];

// make range array 0 - 8
let randIndexes = Array.from({length: 9}, (_,i) => i)
// shuffle it
randIndexes.forEach((_, i, a) => {
  const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
  [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
})

// use the indexes to access the array however you please.
randIndexes.forEach(index => console.log(items[index]))
```

You could, of course, shuffle you `items` array directly if you didn't mind mixing up the order.